# How to create temp table in view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

there are real time CRM data in TMP_HELLO, just hope to get the latest product by seq

```
CREATE VIEW dbcrm.V_HELLO AS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (count int);
insert into temp_table select max(seq) from dbcrm.TMP_HELLO group by ProductID;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT minute(aa.UpdateOn) - minute(aa.TickTime), aa.* 
FROM dbcrm.TMP_HELLO aa
where aa.seq in (select count from temp_table) limit 10000;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

this view is for linked server of MS SQL Server to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use temp tables when creating views. See the [MSDN - CREATE VIEW](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) page; Specifically see the section on "The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:"

If you're actually using Microsoft SQL Server (and not MySQL as the tags on your question suggest) you can use a CTE instead of a temp table. A couple of good pages about CTEs:

[SQL Server CTE Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

[MSDN - Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[MSDN - WITH common_table_expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: -1 OP is using MySQL. Clear from the tags and query text. Also clear when he says the view is accessed by MSSQL via a linked server.

Comment: Regardless of the database you can't use temp tables in a view, so my answer is still correct. Just the advice on what to do instead doesn't help. And IMHO it isn't very clear at all what they're doing so I thought I'd suggest a CTE just in case.